# grep - exclude string which is not a substring of a string

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I explain my problem on Ubuntu 16.04 with the following example: The file is:

```
# cat file
aaa
aaaxxx
aaaxxx*aaa
aaa=aaaxxx
bbbaaaccc
aaaddd/aaaxxx
```

I want to display all lines which contain `aaa` but not in the **only** combination of `aaaxxx`. I want an output like this:

```
# grep SOMETHING-HERE file …
aaa
aaaxxx*aaa (second aaa is the hit)
aaa=aaaxxx (first aaa is the hit)
bbbaaaccc (aaa in any other combination but not aaaxxx)
aaaddd/aaaxxx (similar to above)
```

I tried things like `grep -v aaaxxx file | grep aaa` which results:

```
aaa
bbbaaaccc
```

or

```
# egrep -P '(?<!aaaxxx )aaa' file
grep: die angegebenen Suchmuster stehen in Konflikt zueinander (the pattern are in contradiction)
```

Is there any (simple) possibility? Of course it doesn’t need to be `grep`.
Thanks

Comment: "but in the only combination of `aaaxxx`" - don't you mean except `aaaxxx`?

Comment: So, you want all lines that contain `aaa` followed by anything except `xxx`?

Comment: @Byte Commander Sorry I forgot a `not`. I updated the question

Comment: @terdon not if the line only contain only `aaaxxx`. However I want lines with `aaa` and `aaaxxx`. Puh!

Comment: So a line that contains `aaaxxx` but no other occurrence of `aaa` shall still match?

Comment: @musbach so you want *all* lines matching `aaa`, including those matching `aaaxxx` but not lines that have only `aaaxxx`. So, `aaa` is fine, `aaaxxxfoo` is fine, but `aaaxxx` alone should be skipped?

Comment: @terdon yes you are right. I had really problem to formulate my question. But if one discusses it, it becomes easier. Also the title is a bit ugly and hard to understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's straightforward using a perl-style lookahead operator - available in grep's Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) mode using the `-P` switch:

```
$ grep -P 'aaa(?!xxx)' file
aaa
aaaxxx*aaa
aaa=aaaxxx
bbbaaaccc
aaaddd/aaaxxx
```

(bold formatting in the output indicates the matched parts highlighted by `grep`)

---

Although the zero-length lookahead is convenient, you could achieve the same output using GNU Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax, for example by matching `aaa` followed by up to 2 `x` characters followed by a non-`x` character or end-of-line i.e.

```
grep -E 'aaax{0,2}([^x]|$)' file
```

or even using GNU basic regular expression (BRE) syntax

```
grep 'aaax\{0,2\}\([^x]\|$\)' file
```

which match as

```
aaa
aaaxxx*aaa
aaa=aaaxxx
bbbaaaccc
aaaddd/aaaxxx
```

Comment: Blegh, few seconds faster than me...

Comment: Hope you don't mind me highlighting the output a bit.

Comment: @ByteCommander no problem, not smart enough to do it myself ;)

Comment: @musbach I don't understand. This doesn't do [what you seem to want](http://askubuntu.com/questions/845232/grep-exclude-string-which-is-not-a-substring-of-a-string#comment1296177_845232). It will not match `aaaxxxfoo` for example.

Comment: @terdon it is right that it will not match `aaaxxxfoo`. But I can live with it. In practice I want to search for variables in source code. A variable `VAR` has sometimes derived variables like `VAR_MAX` or `VAR_MIN`. If I only want to search for `VAR` and not for the other ones, I can exclude it by `grep -P 'VAR(?!\_M)' file`. An advanced feature would be If I want to exclude `VARA` and `VARB`. I can do it by concatenating two greps: `grep -P 'VAR(?!A)' file | grep -P 'VAR(?!B)'`.

Comment: @musbach or you can use the `-x` or `-w` flags for `grep`. There are various things you can do, but you need to explain exactly what you need when asking. For the specific case in your comment, you could just do `grep -P 'VAR(?!A|B)'`.