# grep - excluding upfront string

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

This question is similar to that [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845232/grep-exclude-string-which-is-not-a-substring-of-a-string) but I want to exclude a string upfront. Suppose the file:

```
cVar=
 cVar=
1 cVar=
Var=
 Var=
```

I want to grep `Var` but not `cVar`. I tried `grep -P '(?!c)Var' file` but I get all lines of the file. When I try `grep -P ' (?!c)Var' file` (please note the blank before the bracket) I get the last line as it should be.

A `*` or`.` doesn't help.

I tested it on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 14.04 LTS and 10.04 LTS. Always the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) syntax, `(?!c)` is a negative look*ahead*, whereas what you want in this case is a negative look*behind*

```
$ grep -P '(?<!c)Var' file
Var=
 Var=
```

See [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)